# About the order of controller and action in Rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to realize the following:

```
get ':controller/:id/:action(.format)' ,:controller=>'mem'
```

When I visit `/mem/1/follows` I got error:

```
The action '1' could not be found for MemController
```

What should I do to realize this format routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, essentially you are routing `/mem/1/follows` to controller named `MemController`, then Rails will look for the action you are targeting.

In your case, `:id` should be matched as the targeting action, rather than the *id* of some member.

Comment: Then,have any other way?